# How to download Devexpress Project converter?

Tags: devexpress-mvc

I want to upgrade version of DevExpress from Version=13.2.6.0 to new version that is Version = 14.1
But it needs Project converter and I am not getting how to download it. Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project converter is installed automatically on your system when you install the DevExpress components. So, if you install the 14.1 components, You'll have the project converter.

Go to https://www.devexpress.com/ClientCenter/DownloadManager/, enter your account details (user name and password), choose your subscription, and in the drop down menu select Version v14.1.x. to download. Download and install ".Net Controls & Libraries Installer". When done search your system for the "Project Convertor 14.1"

Regards,

Steven